# Facebook post to wall £ shows up as special character

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, special-characters

I am trying to post a message to the facebook feed / wall / timeline that has a £ symbol in it.

I have tried:

```
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
$message = "TEST: £ &pound; &#163;";
```

and setting:

```
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
mb_http_output( "UTF-8" );
```

No luck...

The PHP document is saved as UTF8.

Anyone know how to post a £ symbol to the wall via a php script? The post mechanism is working fine.

So one of the values on the array facebook gets is:

```
$message = "TEST: £ &pound; &#163;";
$DataArray["message"] = $message;
```

and the FB command is:

```
$result = $facebook->api("/me/feed", "post", $DataArray);
```

Result is a diamond shape with ? in it. � for the £ symbol the others just write out.

Comment: A diamond shaped with ? in it.    �

Comment: You say you've encoded the character as UTF-8, are you sending the charset header so that the receiving system knows that it's UTF-8?

Comment: You send an array to facebook. if you can encode an array with headers thats news to me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the reason. I was using ScriptFTP to batch upload files, Filezilla sorted it out. It mus t have been changing the format or something during upload.

Comment: The file probably needed to be uploaded in binary mode. Filezilla must detect which mode to upload in automatically. I know I recently had a problem uploading UCS-2 Little Endian files with Filezilla and had to manually set .txt files to upload in Binary mode. Glad you fixed your problem.

Answer (score 0):

> �

This is usually a sign for an invalid UTF-8 character.

My bet is that your PHP file is ISO-8859-1 encoded. The pound sign has a different code point in ISO-8859-1 than in UTF-8. When data from the PHP file is used in a UTF-8 context, the pound sign becomes invalid.

Save the PHP file with UTF-8 encoding - this can usually be set in the editor's "Save As" dialog.

Comment: Already is saved as UTF8. It's the default encoding in my code editor.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but in my case was that my php file was encoded in ANSI, I just needed to change the file encoding to UTF-8

remember to do this when you have special characters if he were invalid so remember to edit these characters after changing the file encoding

I have helped you or others xD